# Cannot import jdl files

Tags: java, jhipster, jdl

I have a problem with JHipster. I cannot import any JDL Files in projects just created from scratch. Even the jdl-samples from JHipster don't work. I always get the same error:

```
events.js:182
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: ERROR! 
Error while parsing entities from JDL

at Environment.error (/project/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:140:40)
at constructor.error (/project/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base.js:1686:18)
at constructor.parseJDL (/project/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/import-jdl/index.js:108:22)
at Object.<anonymous> (/project/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:417:23)
at /project/node_modules/run-async/index.js:25:25
at Promise (<anonymous>)
at /project/node_modules/run-async/index.js:24:19
at /project/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:418:9
at runCallback (timers.js:781:20)
at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:743:5)
```

With --debug option:
Command:

```
yo jhipster:import-jdl ~/Downloads/example.jh
```

Output:

```
The jdl is being parsed.
DEBUG! Error:
{ name: 'NoSQLModelingException',
  message: 'NoSQL entities don\'t have relationships.',
  prototype: Error
at new BuildException (/Users/jega/projects/owcHandwerker/plattformapp/node_modules/jhipster-core/lib/exceptions/exception_factory.js:42:25)
at checkNoSQLModeling (/Users/jega/projects/owcHandwerker/plattformapp/node_modules/jhipster-core/lib/parser/entity_parser.js:70:11)
at Object.parse [as convertToJHipsterJSON] (/Users/jega/projects/owcHandwerker/plattformapp/node_modules/jhipster-core/lib/parser/entity_parser.js:40:5)
at constructor.parseJDL (/Users/jega/projects/owcHandwerker/plattformapp/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/import-jdl/index.js:93:42)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jega/projects/owcHandwerker/plattformapp/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:417:23)
at /Users/jega/projects/owcHandwerker/plattformapp/node_modules/run-async/index.js:25:25
at Promise (<anonymous>)
at /Users/jega/projects/owcHandwerker/plattformapp/node_modules/run-async/index.js:24:19
at /Users/jega/projects/owcHandwerker/plattformapp/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:418:9
at runCallback (timers.js:781:20) }
Error jhipster:import-jdl /Users/jega/Downloads/example.jh --debug 

Error: ERROR! 
Error while parsing entities from JDL

at Environment.error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:157:40)
at constructor.error (/Users/jega/projects/owcHandwerker/plattformapp/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base.js:1686:18)
at constructor.parseJDL (/Users/jega/projects/owcHandwerker/plattformapp/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/import-jdl/index.js:108:22)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jega/projects/owcHandwerker/plattformapp/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:417:23)
at /Users/jega/projects/owcHandwerker/plattformapp/node_modules/run-async/index.js:25:25
at Promise (<anonymous>)
at /Users/jega/projects/owcHandwerker/plattformapp/node_modules/run-async/index.js:24:19
at /Users/jega/projects/owcHandwerker/plattformapp/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:418:9
at runCallback (timers.js:781:20)
at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:743:5)
```

The JDL File I tried is from the JHipster Blog-Example found here:
https://github.com/jhipster/jdl-samples/blob/master/blog.jh

Comment: Run with the `--debug` flag to get a more verbose error.  Also please add your JDL so we can help

Comment: @JonRuddell I edited the post and added the informations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to generate entities that use relationships in a NoSQL project.  Relations are not supported by JHipster for NoSQL projects.  For more information on how JHipster handles relationships, see the docs on [Managing Relationships](http://www.jhipster.tech/managing-relationships/):

> Relationships only work when JPA is used. If you choose to use Cassandra or MongoDB, they won’t be available.

Removing the relationships allows the JDL to be imported.  You can also try with a project using an SQL database option.

The JDL error message is more verbose in future versions of JHipster (v4.10.0+) so you won't need to use the `--debug` flag in the future.